# expl3 read a comma list from file

Tags: expl3, latex3, comma-separated-list, token-lists, interfaces

I am using `expl3` now, I want to read data from file, and store them in a `comma list`, then use the `comma list` one by one.

I don't have any code, I just know `exp13` have these function, so need someone help me.

(I guess `\seq_gset_from_clist:NN` maybe used after store the following data in a `comma list`.)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
 1.23
 -3.78
 1.23
 -3.78
\end{filecontents*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Official answer

Open a read stream and map it line by line.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
 1.23
 -3.78
 1.23
 -3.78
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g_zongxian_readfile_stream
\ior_open:Nn \g_zongxian_readfile_stream { \jobname.dat }
\clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
\ior_map_inline:Nn \g_zongxian_readfile_stream
 { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 } }

\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\stop
```

## Unofficial answer

Setting `\endlinechar` has no real interface in `expl3`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
 1.23
 -3.78
 1.23
 -3.78
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \endlinechar=`, } { \jobname.dat }
\clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl

\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\stop
```

## Output on the console for both methods

```
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1.23}
>  {-3.78}
>  {1.23}
>  {-3.78}.
```